# java String start and end position

Tags: java, string

I have one string and I want to check start and end position.
For example, my String is "I am new User in  https://stackoverflow.com/". I would like to show only "User" in this String.
How can I solve this problem?

I want to show String between new and in. Start position new and end position in. result User 
I tried this code

```
String source = "I am new User in  https://stackoverflow.com/";
    int indexOfP = source.indexOf("User");

    String result = source.substring(indexOfP, indexOfP + 4);
    System.out.println(result); // prints 'User '
```

but I do not know length of my String.

Comment: Why do you want to crop out a word that you already know?

Comment: whats the question ? your code seems to do what you trying to explain?

Comment: i want to show String between new and in.Start position new and end position in.result User

Comment: Then you should definitely edit your question. It's very unclear.

Comment: Still. Is it always `new` and `in`, or the nth word? The problem as you describe it can be solved by `System.out.println("User")`

Answer (score 3):

Why just don't use [`String.length()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length%28%29)? 
For example:

```
String source = "I am new User in  http://stackoverflow.com/";
String needle = "User";
int indexOfP = source.indexOf(needle);

String result = source.substring(indexOfP, indexOfP + needle.length());
System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: i want to show String between new  and in.Start position new and end position in.result User

Comment: You know "new" and "in"? I mean, are these words constant?

Answer (score 1):

If it is always the same String and only the username changes:

```
String source = "I am new username in http://stackoverflow.com/";
int indexOfNew = source.indexOf("new");
int indexOfIn = source.indexOf("in");

String result = source.substring(indexOfNew + 4, indexOfIn - 1);
System.out.println(result); // prints username
```

Comment: thanks but it is not same String

Comment: put some more examples in your question, some sentences with different usernames I guess?

Answer (score 0):

```
// The words are delimited by spaces
String[] tokens = source.split(" ");

// ... and you want the 4th word
result = tokens[3];
```

Comment: i do not neew this solution because meybe String is changed and i do not know String Lenght.simple i want start and end position.that's all

Comment: Would only work if the username does not contain spaces, which isn't clear in the question. If that isn't the case, this will be the best solution